# Pseudocode what is the output?

Tags: pseudocode

I am finding it hard to find what this pseudocode outputs. Does it mean for example if you entered the name `Peter`. Would the output be `pet`? Or the letter `t`?

```
Display enter a name
Get name
Length = length of name 
Index = length -1 
While index >= 0 Do
      DISPLAY name(index)
      Index = index -2 
ENDWHILE
```

Comment: Pseudocodes have nothing to do with python.

Comment: Can't you execute it step by step on paper? This is _pseudocode_, not Python.

Comment: I don't understand the psedocode. As in for example what it's doing exactly. I just want to understand what it's saying. Because I don't know if it's taking numbers away from a name a user enters. Or if it's removing all letters and keeping the 3 letter of say Peter. Because it's -2. Thanks for the quick  reply.

Comment: It displays the letters in reverse order, skipping one every time. So `Timothy` gets displayed as `ytmT`.

Comment: Thanks I understood now. Had the wrong idea I was thinking just -2 letters is too simple. It's the index= part. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It displays the letters in reverse order, skipping one every time. So `Timothy` gets displayed as `ytmT`.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript, which you can test:

```js
var display = '';
var name = prompt("Enter a name:");
length = name.length; 
index = length - 1;
while (index >= 0) {
      display += name[index];
      index = index -2 
}
alert(display);
```

Comment: Thank you. Actully runs on my phone. Tried different names out. Understood :)